# QGIS won't import this line of WKT and I don't know why

Tags: qgis, wkt

I have been trying to import a CSV file and QGIS does not like this one line:

```
"POLYGON((41.8333 54.5203, 41.5 54.5068, 41.434 54.5, 41.1667 54.3396, 40.8333 54.2923, 40.5 54.2192, 40.1667 54.1807, 40.1498 54.1667, 40.0896 53.8333, 40.1667 53.7839, 40.4581 53.5, 40.5 53.4114, 40.7319 53.1667, 40.8333 52.8913, 40.8784 52.8333, 40.8333 52.7964, 40.5073 52.5, 40.5 52.4934, 40.1667 52.4594, 39.8333 52.3378, 39.5 52.313, 39.2507 52.5, 39.1667 52.5114, 38.8333 52.5337, 38.5 52.5125, 38.1667 52.505, 37.9059 52.5, 37.8333 52.4927, 37.8253 52.5, 37.5488 52.8333, 37.5263 53.1667, 37.5221 53.5, 37.5412 53.8333, 37.8333 54.1476, 37.8491 54.1667, 38.1667 54.4656, 38.4594 54.5, 38.5 54.5338, 38.8333 54.7174, 39.1667 54.794, 39.5 54.8166, 39.5741 54.8333, 39.8333 55.058, 40.1298 55.1667, 40.1667 55.2005, 40.5 55.3991, 40.8333 55.4617, 41.1667 55.4447, 41.5 55.4281, 41.8333 55.4139))",9,p666,0
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong (or right with all the other entries)... 
Sample of an entry QGIS accepts:

```
"POLYGON((39.8324 52.8333, 39.8333 52.8343, 40.1667 53.1582, 40.5 53.1582, 40.8308 52.8333, 40.8266 52.5, 40.5 52.181, 40.1667 52.1807, 39.8394 52.5, 39.8333 52.8311, 39.8324 52.8333))",7,P9,200,99.98
```

QGIS only states the entry is not a valid WKT with no further explanation or estimate on where the error is. I have tried the WKT in online services and they do not seem to complain about it...

I tried using the following sites to see if there is anything wrong with my WKT but they all run the WKT just fine:

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html

http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

https://clydedacruz.github.io/openstreetmap-wkt-playground/

If anybody has a clue on where is my mistake, I would appreciate.

PS: for the record, I have already spent 2 days trying to figure this out, so fresh eyes are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The polygon was not closed (meaning the first point should have been repeated as the last point).

A polygon of points a b and c needs to be ((a, b, c, a)) where a is lon lat in point a, and so on.

Example:

```
POLYGON((0 3, 10 24, -5 -60, 0 3))
```

It ends and starts with the same point (in the example [0 3]).

The websites I have been testing the wkt were correcting it on my behalf (adding the last point).